Cargar bitmap en wxPython (Python 3.12)
Estoy tratando de cargar un bitmap PNG en wxPhyton y Python 3.12. No me da ningún tipo de error pero la ventana aparece vacía, en blanco.
Aquí dejo el código por si alguien localiza el error:
import os, wx

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title = "Bitmaps")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="",
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize,
                 style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, name="MyFrame"):

        super().__init__(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        img_path = os.path.abspath("./Media/Images/Face-grin.png")
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(img_path, type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, bitmap=bitmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()

Gracias de antemano.

Your code works for me. Is the path correct? is the image really png?

Hola Torkan, tu código en principio se ve correcto y en mi caso al menos funciona sin problemas en Python 3.12/wx-Python 4.2.1 (Linux). Por descartar problemas con la propia imagen, si no lo has hecho ya, prueba con otras, por ejemplo https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo-master-v3-TM-flattened.png Una ruta incorrecta debería generar un diálogo de error.

Para mi Python 3.11//wx-Python 4.2.1 (Linux).

Mirando vuestros comentarios he descubierto el problema, la imagen es demasiado grande, ¿alguna manera de modificar el tamaño de la imagen desde dentro del programa?

@Torkan eso lo explica :) Mira mi respuesta a ver si te es de ayuda. Sería conveniente que editaras la pregunta para reflejar el problema real ahora que lo conocemos, ya que tal como la tienes efectivamente no se puede reproducir el problema.

Si tu imagen es demasiado grande con respecto al widget que la muestra puede que efectivamente termines viendo solo una fracción de la esquina superior izquierda de la misma. Si se le suma que es una imagen con transparencia puede resultar en que, aparentemente, la imagen no se esté mostrando.
Para reescalar una imagen desde WxPython puedes hacer uso de la clase  wx.Image y usar:

wx.Image.Rescale: escala la imagen in-place, es preferible si no necesitas para nada más la imagen original.
img_path = os.path.abspath("./Media/Images/Face-grin.png")
img = wx.Image(img_path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Rescale(200, 200)
bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, bitmap=bitmap)


wx.Image.Scale: escala la imagen pero retorna una nueva instancia de wx.Image con la imagen reescala, manteniendo la original intacta. Si vas a usar la imagen original más veces te convine este método para no tener que volver a cargarla desde el disco.
img_path = os.path.abspath("./Media/Images/Face-grin.png")
img = wx.Image(img_path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(img.Scale(200, 200))
self.bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, bitmap=bitmap)



Ambos métodos aceptan tres argumentos, el ancho, el alto y la calidad. Este último argumento es opcional (con valor wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_NORMAL por defecto) e indica el algoritmo usado para reescalar la imagen. Sus valores posibles están definidos en el enum wx.ImageResizeQuality.

Nota: Existen otro par de métodos relacionados (wx.Image.Resize y wx.Image.Size) con el mismo comportamiento in-place/no in-place y que también permiten modificar el tamaño de la imagen, pero en vez de aplicar un reescalado llevan a cabo un recortado (cropping) de la misma.

Gracias por el aviso @DanteS, efectivamente tenía un error en la url que la hacía inválida. Corregido.
